# Can we send ajax from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

since I wrote this code and it turned out that it is not entering the if statement ,My target was to bring the array from php(db) and put it in array in js,what to do?Here is the code ,is the problem that it is located  in an extension  js  file  ?Moreover php file getusercatpref.php is returning ["violen","ios","programming","nodjs"].

```
var arr = new Array();
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        arr = myArr;

    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getusercatpref.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP Code

```
<?php 
$name="root"; 
$pas=""; 
$dbname="jobpursuit"; 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", $name, $pas,$dbname); 
$arrayCategories = array(); 
$sql="Select * FROM preferences where username='12' "; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$index=0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $arrayCategories[$index] = $row['categoryname']; 
    $index=$index+1; 
} 
echo json_encode($arrayCategories); 
?>
```

Comment: Of course, The J in AJAX stands for Javascript

Comment: Did you try `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `this.responseText`

Comment: It would probably be useful to see the PHP code as well

Comment: yep,same it didn't work

Comment: it is fetched from db where and encoded into json

Comment: For future reference, Nobody can read code in a comment. However you can EDIT your question any number of times when additional information is requested, code is readable in the question

Comment: Perhaps you ought to set the `Content-Type` header.. ie: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` after the `xmlhttp.open()` call

Comment: also it might be worth noting that populating, or trying to populate, a global variable from within the callback will not necessarily work as you might expect. You ought to use the callback to fully process the response data rather than hope the global variable will be correctly populated when it is needed by some other function

Comment: I can't see that the problem is from a global variable since it is not entering the if statement .

Comment: no- I don't believe that is the issue - it was simply a point of interest should you discover that you were unable to use that variable later.  The ajax code seems to work OK so it suggests the issue lies elsewhere

Comment: yeah I realized that now ,thanks ,but should I use it with a global variable?